# How to upload a photo to a specific album and if not exist create that album?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a app that upload a photo to users profile

but when it upload a photo it goes to a new album named with a app name.

what i want to do is upload photo to a album named by me like

"my test album" or some thing.

and when the album my test album doesn't exist it should create a album "my test album".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first upload you can create the album :

```
$facebook->api('/me/albums','post',$album_details);
```

and save the album_id that is returned.
  Then for sequential uploads you can make calls to :

```
$facebook->api('/'.$album_id.'/photos','post',$photo_details);
```

It is all covered in [this facebook developers blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498).

Comment: thats what i am asking how to create a album?

Answer (score 3):

First you want to check to see if the album you are creating exists, otherwise Facebook will keep generating the same album with the same name.

```
$album = $facebook->api($param);
if (!$album) {
    $album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Your album description goes here',
        'name'=> $albumName
    );  
    $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);
    $album_uid = $create_album['id'];
} else {
    $album_uid = $album[0]['object_id'];
}
```

Once you've got the album id, you can upload your photo like so:

```
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> 'Photo Description Goes Here',
    'image'=> '@' . realpath($theUploadFile)
);

$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

I wrote a good tutorial that has this feature in it among many others. My photo upload features is built in with a multi-select and allows you to upload photos and videos at the same time. You can view the entire tutorial and download the package here: http://www.epixseo.com/index.php/facebook-php-3-3-1-and-javascript-sdk-graph-api-tutorial/