# How to specify ALBUM NAME + DESCRIPTION on photo upload, and NOT base it on APP name? (Facebook Timeline)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I use this script here for my Facebook App.
It uploads a photo on a user's Facebook profile, and creates a new album for that photo.

The script returns "***[APP NAME]* Photos**" as the Album name / title (without quotations).
- ***[APP NAME]*** being the name of my Facebook APP -

Basically, I don't want that Album title. I want to specify an Album title on the script.
**What I want is :**

- **... to be able to specify the Album's name / title to create, from the script.**
- **And if possible, specify Album description too.**

This is the script -

```php
    $root_url = "http://www.WEBSITE.COM/";
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

      // Get image from URL
      $img = $_GET['i'];
      // Change location depending on which type of cover
      if($get_set != 1) {
      $photo = './PATH/'.$img.''; // Path to the photo on the local filesystem
      } else {
      $photo = './PATH/'.$img.'';
      }
      $message = 'THIS IS THE PHOTO CAPTION';




        if($user_id) {

          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {

            // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
            // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
            // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path 
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                             'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                             'message' => $message,
                                             )
                                          );
          //  echo '<pre>Photo ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
          print "<script>window.location = '".$root_url."index.php?cover=uploaded'</script>";

          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'photo_upload'
                           )); 
            echo '<script> window.location = "' . $login_url . '"; </script>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   

          echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
        } else {

          // No user, print a link for the user to login
          // To upload a photo to a user's wall, we need photo_upload  permission
          // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
          // need to specify it here.
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload') );
            echo '<script> window.location = "' . $login_url . '"; </script>';
            //echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login</a> to continue.';

        }
```

Seeing this one **[here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/)**, I am confident that is possible.

```php
   $album_name = 'YOUR_ALBUM_NAME';
   $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';
```

I just don't know how to work it in there...
Looking forward to solutions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload images to a specific Facebook Album](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4509326/upload-images-to-a-specific-facebook-album)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the documentation of the [Photo object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/):

> you can upload a photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo
>   content and an optional description to one these to Graph API
>   connections:
>
> - https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos - The photo will be published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an
>     album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded
>     this way will then be added to this same album.
> - https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos - The photo will be published to a specific, existing photo album, represented by the
>     ALBUM_ID. Regular albums have a size limit of 200 photos. Default
>     application albums have a size limit of 1000 photos.

You are currently using the first option, using the 2nd one requires for you to have an album id, which you first need to create:

> You can create an album for a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   PROFILE_ID/albums with the publish_stream permissions and the
>   following parameters
>   ([Albums connection of the User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums))

The problem is that you'll have to save this album id for the user to use in the future when the app needs to upload again to the album.

Comment: I see, that was stated very clearly & I definitely understood that. Thank you. I've stumbled on a few posts (like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8843669/1399030) and going through on its linked tutorial it's looking very confusing to me. I'm looking for the right code to integrate into my existing one, so I could have it work the way I want, since I'm not sure exactly how to do that seamlessly myself, I've asked. I'm really hoping someone could throw me a snippet or two. :o)

Comment: The simplest thing to do is just leave it as it is, otherwise you're starting to add complexity. You'll either need to find out the id of the app created album, and then modify it's data, or you'll need to store the user created album id for that specific user, then every time check if the user already has an album.

Comment: Thanks @Nitzan, you're right! I guess I'd have to stick it out with this one. Thanks for your time! You definitely showed me the direction I needed to go in order to get what I wanted, and that since it's a harder path you've shown me as well that I'm better off keeping my current one. Thank you for your input, I found your comments very helpful. & Yes, I do think you have it correct. I've decided to leave it as it is. :) **Unless somebody just actually hands me a working modified code of the current one I'm using, LOL, then I'd be happy to use that instead.**